# minimum of two exponential random variables over an interval $[0,T]$ instead of $[0,\infty]$

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

Let $X_i$, $X_j$ be two independent exponentially distributed random variables with rate parameters $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$.  Then we know that

$\min\left\{X_i,  X_j \right\}$

is also exponentially distributed, with parameter

$\lambda = \lambda_i +  \lambda_j$.

The index of the variable which achieves the minimum is distributed according to the categorical distribution

$\Pr\left(k \mid X_k = \min\{X_i,  X_j\}\right) = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_i +  \lambda_j}$.

A proof is as follows (Borrowed from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

$ I = \operatorname{argmin}_{ \{i, j\}}\{X_i,  X_j\}$

$\begin{align}
      \text{then } \Pr (I = i) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \Pr(X_i = x) \Pr(X_{j} > x ) dx \\
      &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x}  e^{-\lambda_j x} dx \\
      &= \lambda_i \int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{-\left(\lambda_i  +\lambda_j\right) x}  dx \\
      &= \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i +  \lambda_j}.
\end{align}$

**My question** is suppose now we want the above probability within the interval  $[0,T]$ instead of $[0,\infty]$, in other words, what is the probablity that  $X_i$ precedes  $X_j$ within the $[0,]$. I found a formula stating that this probablity is then
$ \Pr (I = i) = \frac{\lambda_j e^{-(\lambda_i  +\lambda_j)T} +(-\lambda_i  -\lambda_j) e^{-\lambda_j T}+\lambda_i}{\lambda_i +  \lambda_j}
$, but I could not verify it or prove it.

Comment: Could you explicitly state the probability you want? "Probability for the interval of $[0,T]$" is not clear.

Comment: @angryavian, I tried to explain better, I would like to find the probablity that precedes  within this limited interval $[0,T]$.

Comment: Do you want $P(X_i < X_j < T)$ or $P(\{X_i < T\} \cap \{X_i < X_j\}) = P(X_i < \min\{X_j, T\})$?

Comment: @angryavian, thanks a lot, yes, I want $P(\{X_i < T\} \cap \{X_i < X_j\}) = P(X_i < \min\{X_j, T\})$.

Comment: @angryavian, the first integral gives me the answer after some algebraic simplifications, is the first integral in your answer the same as $P(X_i < X_j < T)$ ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

The joint density of $(X_i, X_j)$ is $f(x_i, x_j) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x_i} \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j x_j}$. You just need to integrate this over the region of the $(x_i, x_j)$-plane where $x_i < \min\{x_j, T\}$. If you draw a picture, this region can be broken up into a triangle and an infinite rectangular strip.

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\min\{x_j, T\}} f(x_i, x_j) \, dx_i \, dx_j
= \int_0^T \int_0^{x_j} f(x_i, x_j) \, dx_i \, dx_j
+ \int_T^\infty \int_0^T f(x_i, x_j) \, dx_i \, dx_j.$$

The first integral is
$$\int_0^T \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j x_j} \int_0^{x_j} \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x_i} \, dx_i \, dx_j
= \int_0^T \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j x_j} (1 - e^{-\lambda_i x_j}) \, dx_j
= 1 - e^{-\lambda_j T} - \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j} (1-e^{-(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)T}).$$

The second integral is
$$\int_T^\infty \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j x_j} \int_0^T \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x_i} \, dx_i \, dx_j
=e^{-\lambda_j T}(1 - e^{-\lambda_i T})$$

The sum of these two terms doesn't quite match up with your answer, but it is similar. Maybe one of us made a mistake somewhere.

---

Update: as pointed out by OP, the first integral gives the answer, which suggests that OP actually wanted to compute $P(X_i < X_j < T)$.

Comment: @ angryavian,  thanks a lot, it solved my problem :-)